How to configure Flink to run from particular desired timestamp?
I am new to Flink and trying to understand if we can configure the Flink to run from particular desired timestamp?
I have a scenario for this i wanted to test this. If my Flink job fails and unable to get into run for more than 1 hour I have a data delay in delivery.
For this condition I have a fallback job which runs in batch and ingest the data into desired DB.
Example:
Flink job fails at 9:15 AM and I need to run batch job for 9-10 & 10-11 AM hour.
From 11 AM i again need to switch back to my Flink job so for this i need to set some config so that flink will understand not to run from last failure (9:15 AM) but from the give desired timestamp.(11 AM)
Is this is possible with flink?

This is possible, but the details vary depending on the source. E.g., are you using Kafka?

Never mind, I see you got an answer in another forum.
